# Finding files stored by Xamarin on Android in Flutter

Tags: flutter, xamarin, directory

Here's an interesting one. I'm working on a Flutter app that will replace an old Xamarin app. One of the customer's criteria is to read an sqlite database written by the Xamarin app into a new database in the Flutter app. I think I've figured out the location of the old database in iOS, but I need a hand finding it in Android.

In the Xamarin code the database is stored using this:

```cs
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var dbPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, Filename);
```

In Flutter I have the `getDatabasesPath()` function which I believe returns `data/data/<package_name>/databases`.

What I need to figure out is where the Xamarin code is storing the database file, and how I can then navigate to that in Flutter using the returned value from `getDatabasesPath()` as the starting point.

Anyone tried this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396105/specialfolder-personal-location

Comment: Hi, you could have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898985/how-can-i-get-my-db-file-or-filepath-in-flutter), it may be helpful.