# Error ")" near first line when building SQLite database

Tags: database, sqlite

I am trying to a build an SQLite database from an existing CSV file following the steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51387985/3562088). However I already get an error in the second step where the database should be created from the defined table with

```
sqlite3 worldcities.db < worldcities.sql
```

The error message reads

```
Error: near line 1: near ")": syntax error
```

My worldcities.sql file looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE worldcities(
   city TEXT NOT NULL,
   city_ascii TEXT NOT NULL,
   lat REAL NOT NULL,
   lng REAL NOT NULL,
   country TEXT NOT NULL,
   iso2 TEXT NOT NULL,
   iso3 TEXT NOT NULL,
   admin_name TEXT NOT NULL,
   capital TEXT NOT NULL,
   population INT NOT NULL,
   id INT NOT NULL,
);
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: I am surprised by the `,` before the `)`. Maybe SQLite also is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the orphaned `,` just before your `)`to cause your problem.

I tried here https://extendsclass.com/sqlite-browser.html
this

```
CREATE TABLE newtoy2 (MID INT, BID INT);
```

without a problem.

But this, having the same problem I suspect in your code

```
CREATE TABLE newtoy1 (MID INT, BID INT,);
```

gets the same error you quote: `near ")": syntax error`

Which confirms my suspicion.

Comment: An *orphaned ,* is a typo and a reason for a question to be closed.

Comment: Or it is a misunderstanding of syntax which, pointed out, results in a helpful insight.

Answer (score 1):

There was an extra comma ',' before end of block.
Commas are used after all column description but not after the last column description.

Try and Run this below code.

```
   create table worldcities(
   city TEXT NOT NULL,
   city_ascii TEXT NOT NULL,
   lat REAL NOT NULL,
   lng REAL NOT NULL,
   country TEXT NOT NULL,
   iso2 TEXT NOT NULL,
   iso3 TEXT NOT NULL,
   admin_name TEXT NOT NULL,
   capital TEXT NOT NULL,
   population INT NOT NULL,
   id INT NOT NULL);
```